# loopback - validación clave foránea en modelo

Tags: nodejs, loopback

que tal. Estoy tratando de validar una clave foránea en la inserción de un registro, pero no tengo resultado. Mi modelo tiene asociado la propiedad:

```
"options": {"validate": true }
```

Al realizar un POST y pasarle un ID inválido del modelo al cual hace referencia la relación, me deja insertarlo sin problema.

¿Cómo puedo validar la existencia de los IDs referenciados?

Comment: Tu pregunta es muy poco clara, necesitas agregar mas detalles.

Comment: Podrias mostrarnos tu metodo que realiza el POST, quiza tambien tu modelo de Base de Datos, ya que parece que no tienes unas restricción de campos

Comment: Aqui tengo el modelo: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34790938/loopback-foreign-key-validation
Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al no encontrar la manera en que la validación se haga a nivel de modelo de forma automática al ser una relación, tuve que hacerlo de forma manual en el archivo `neighborhood.js` agregando un hook en `before save`.

Aquí les dejo una solución al problema. Espero les sirva.

```
module.exports = function (Neighborhood) {

    Neighborhood.observe('before save', function verifyForeignKeys(ctx, next) {
        if (ctx.instance) { // for single model update
            // check ctx.instance.fkField
            var s = ctx.instance;
            var countryId = s.__data.countryId;            

            //Get the Application object which the model attached to, and we do what ever we want
            Neighborhood.getApp(function (err, app) {
                //App object returned in the callback
                //PersistedModel.exists(id, callback ((err, exists)))
                app.models.Country.exists(countryId, function (err, exists) {
                    if (err) throw err;
                    if (!exists)
                        return next(new Error('Bad foreign key...'));
                });
            });
            next();
        }});
}
```